# forest is not working (update problem?) [resolved]

Tags: ubuntu, forest

I'm working on Ubuntu (16.04 LTS) with TexStudio.

Following the [quickstart tutorial on forest (for linguists)](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/info/forest-quickstart/ForestQuickstart.pdf), I tried the easiest tree possible:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\title{Tree}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{forest}
    [CP[C][IP[I][VP[V][NP]]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

I get a bunch of error messages, beginning with:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfk@/handlers/.wrap 6 pgfmath args/.@@body. }
```

As far as I understood from forums online, I have to update the "pgf" package. But I checked for that (on synaptic package manager), and it seems I already have the latest version (2.10-1).

Does one have any clue how to solve my problem ? (and sorry if this is a terrible beginner question!)

Comment: Do you have `texlive-pictures` installed?

Comment: The latest `pgf` version is 3.0.1a 2015-08-29, see http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf. The error you're getting is due to an old bug in `pgf`, so I recommend an update.

Comment: If you are getting both PGF and Forest from your distro, you should report this as a bug: they should not package a later version of Forest without the version of PGF it requires. Consider using upstream TeX Live.

Comment: @JohannBauer: yes, I have texlive-pictures

Comment: @cfr: I will look for upstream Tex Live, thanks for the indication!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to incompatible versions of PGF and forest

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks for your help, guys! I had a hard time finding out how to do it, but at the end I found [a very good explaination on how to install (updated) Tex Live on Ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#95373).
The problem came from the OS (Ubuntu) and its default Tex Live.

Easy trees (see first message) are working fine now.